# What is the purpose of declaring a protocol for a variable?

Tags: objective-c, protocols, ivar, ivars

I have been reading about Protocols on Objective-C  but I cannot grasp this:

Consider this line

```
Person <CoordinateSupport> *person = [[Person alloc] init];
```

What is the purpose of declaring the variable to conform to the protocol `CoordinateSupport`? Is this something just for compile time, so Xcode can warn me if I assign something different to `person` or is there any purpose at run time?

I cannot see how a variable can conform to a protocol. OK, a class is easy to see, because you can have a protocol defining methods that you want some class to follow but an ivar?

I am not seeing it.

Comment: If it were `id<CoordinateSupport> person = ...`, it would make more sense to me.

Comment: I have copied it [from here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-succinctly-protocols--mobile-22019) but anyway, if you can explain the `id` example using an answer...

Comment: What I mean is, either `Person` implements `CoordinateSupport` or it doesn't.  Putting a protocol annotation on it doesn't change anything.  With `id<CoordinateSupport>`, however, you're saying you don't care about the type of object, only that it provides the services you need.

Comment: So, but your answer doesn't explain why I should do that. I cannot see that without an example... if the class has already using the protocol why should I care to use that declaration on an ivar?

Comment: Ah...sorry.  I thought you were just asking about the value of using `Person` in `Person <CoordinateSupport>` and I couldn't see that there was any.  Are you actually asking about the use of variables that conform to protocols, generally?

Comment: yes. I cannot see a purpose for that.

Comment: @PhillipMills: "What I mean is, either `Person` implements `CoordinateSupport` or it doesn't. Putting a protocol annotation on it doesn't change anything." It does. For example, `Person` can not implement `CoordinateSupport` but a subclass of `Person` can. So it would require it to be a subclass of `Person` that also conforms to `CoordinateSupport`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard pattern when declaring that a variable conforms to a protocol is to give it the "any object" type, `id`. Declaring that a variable both has a specific type *and* conforms to a protocol is typically redundant – I'll explain why later. For now, let's talk about variables of type `id<P>`, where `P` is some protocol, and why they're useful. This type should be read as "an instance of any class that conforms to `P`."

To concretize the discussion that follows, let's define a protocol:

```
@protocol Adder
- (NSInteger)add:(NSInteger)a to:(NSInteger)b;
@end
```

> I cannot see how a variable can conform to a protocol.

This one is easy. A variable conforms to an Objective-C protocol when it represents an instance of a class that implements all of the required methods in the protocol.

```
@interface Abacus : NSObject <Adder>
@end

@implementation Abacus
- (NSInteger)add:(NSInteger)a to:(NSInteger)b { return a + b; }
- (NSInteger)beadCount { return 91; }
@end
```

Given this `Abacus` class, you could, of course, create a new `Abacus`:

```
Abacus *a = [[Abacus alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[a add:5 to:6]);  // 11
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[a beadCount]);   // 91
```

But you could also declare `a` to just be of type `id<Adder`. Remember, that means the type of `a` is "an instance of any class that conforms to `Adder`."

```
id<Adder> a = [[Abacus alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[a add:5 to:6]);  // 11
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[a beadCount]);   // Compile error: No known instance method for selector 'beadCount'
```

The compiler complains because all we said about the type of `a` is that it is a class that conforms to `Adder`, and nowhere in the `Adder` protocol do we say anything about a method named `beadCount`.

> What is the purpose of declaring the variable to conform to [a protocol]?

The purpose is for information hiding. When you want a class that conforms to `Adder`, you don't need to care about what the actual class is – you just get an `id<Adder>`. Imagine that `Abacus` is a system class, and you've written the following code:

```
- (Abacus *)getAdder { return [[Abacus alloc] init]; }
- (void)doWork {
    Abacus *a = [self getAdder];
    // Do lots of adding...
}
```

Then, in iOS 42, Apple comes up with a new innovation – the `Calculator` class! Your friends tell you that `Calculator` adds two numbers together more than twice as fast as `Abacus`, and all the cool kids are using it! You decide to refactor your code, but you realize that not only do you have to change the return type of `getAdder`, but also the types of all the variables to which you assign the return value of `getAdder`! Lame. What if you had done this instead:

```
- (id<Adder>)getAdder { return [[Abacus alloc] init]; }
- (void)doWork {
    id<Adder> *a = [self getAdder];
    // Do lots of adding...
}
```

Now, when you want to migrate to `Calculator`, you just need to change the body of `getAdder` to `return [[Calculator alloc] init]` and you're done! One line. The rest of your code stays exactly the same. In that case, you have *hidden* the true type of the instance returned from `getAdder` from the rest of your code. Information hiding makes refactoring easier.

Lastly, I promised to explain why something like `Abacus <Adder> *a = ...` is usually redundant. What you're saying here is "`a` is an instance of `Abacus` that conforms to `Adder`." But you (and the compiler) already know that `Abacus` conforms to `Adder` – it's right there in the interface declaration! As [rmaddy points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284847/1292061), there are some cases where you want to talk about an instance that is either a given class, or a subclass thereof, and also specify that it conforms to a protocol, but those situations are rare, and most often specifying both a class and protocol conformance is unneeded.

For more information, check out Apple's [Working with Protcols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) guide.

Comment: *"Declaring that a variable both has a specific type and conforms to a protocol is redundant"* - not necessarily. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Agreed. Edited to reflect that.